# After trying to enqueue several Javascript scripts in my Wordpress PHP file, how can I prevent "cannot use import statement outside a module?"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm writing a plugin for my Wordpress php file, which seeks to emulate an HTML file I had previously made, which calls several Javascript in this manner:

```
<script src="./Controller/myfile.js" type="module" defer></script>
```

However, with Wordpress, bc I'm not making a simple .html file, I cannot do that directly. I have enqueued scripts, but when I try to go to where these scripts are run, I see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` and `unexpected token: export` in the browser console. What do I need to put in my .php file to fix this problem?

Comment: I suppose you're enqueing myfile.js and it ends up in the page without `type="module"`. Check out https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/312147/enqueue-script-with-data-attributes for a similar question on how to add an attribute to an enqueued script.

Comment: @Aioros I don't understand what the accepted answer is saying, and how I inject MY script into it.

Comment: I'll try to post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

The file `./Controller/myfile.js` or any other file you enqueue in WP has to be the final output/build of your JS. That means you can't have `import` statements or anything like that since all code must be on that file. This is because once WP renders your file in `<script>`, no further processing happens (i.e. no resolving modules, e.t.c.). I'd recommend using something like [Gulpjs](https://gulpjs.com/) to bundle up your source js code and produce a minified build file which you can then enqueue.

**Edit:**

If your enqueued script doesn't have `type="module"`, then follow Aioros's comment above and enqueue it properly with module as your type attribute. I'd still recommend getting a bundle since `type="module" has limited support` [developer.mozilla.org modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: what would I put into my code that calls my file? That's where I'm confused.

Comment: Aioros's answer covers how you can add `type="module"` to the script which will make it work on most modern browsers. It won't work on IE and will give the same error.  `type="module"` makes it possible for some browsers to natively support `import`s, `export`s etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you enqueue your script with `wp_enqueue_script()`, you end up with a script element like this:

```
<script src="./Controller/myfile.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it doesn't have the `type="module"` attribute, and I imagine that's why you get an error for `import`. There are a few ways to add it.

I don't know how exactly you're registering/enqueuing the script, but let's pretend it's like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script("myfile", "Controller/myfile.js");
```

Then you could add to your plugin a filter like:

```
function add_type_module_attribute($tag, $handle) {
   if ( $handle !== 'myfile' ) {
      return $tag;
   }
   // needed in case you already have a type='javascript' attribute
   $new_tag = str_replace("type='text/javascript'", '', $tag);
   // adding type='module'
   $new_tag = str_replace(" src", " type='module' defer src", $tag);
   return $new_tag;
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_type_module_attribute', 10, 2);
```

Comment: will this work for that ```defer``` attribute I need to be in there?

Comment: `$new_tag = str_replace(" src", " type='module' defer src", $tag);`

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot the `defer`. I'll add @TonyM's suggestion to the answer.